# mouse/touchpad failure 16.04 on dell laptop

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad

installed 16.04 on a dell laptop, after a few minutes the mouse click does not work. Neither mouse or touch pad, then keyboard also stops responding, have to power down to reset.

Finally got back to this.

It is a Dell Latitude E6420. It has been running win7 for several years so I don't think it is a problem with power to the mouse. Also the same issues appear with the touch pad. No response to mouse clicks or keypad although mouse movement(cursor) works with both touch pad and external mouse.
It seems like driver problem but the mouse works fine when I first boot/logon.
The laptop is plugged in to the power supply.

Comment: Please, at least, the laptop's **model** but plreferably edit and add other hardware specs.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is because your system is power of your devices, there are some cases where the system disables the usb ports,

you could give us more information about the system, what devices .
Please run :

lsusb, and put here your output, we can check if your system uses usb drivers for the keyboard and mouse pad.

if yes you can check the next answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux